# Printing table values in ascending order

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to print out a users name and totalspent value in ascending order of totalspent. I.e, user that has spent the most will be outputed first then the next highest spender etc.

This is my current code, however, this only seems to output a single table row an infinite amount of times.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * FROM `members` ORDER BY `totalspent` DESC LIMIT 10) tmp order by tmp.totalspent asc";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['name'] . " - $" . $row['totalspent'] . "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

select member_name, totalspent from tmp order by totalspent desc;

still can you show snippet of your table and snippet of answer you desire

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can prefer for you to join two tables. The code should like follows-

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM temp.tmp, mem.members WHERE temp.totalspend = mem.totalspend ORDER by temp.totalspend ASC";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['name'] . " - $" . $row['totalspent'] . "<br/>";
}
```

I believe, it will work for your smoothly... TQ